# Car movement in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a game in unity and this game uses a car. I want to move the car and so far I can move it forward and backward, and I can also rotate it to left and right and these two moves work fine.

But after I rotate it to the right and i try to make it moves forward it move in the same direction as before without taking into account the turn just made. The move it makes it is like moving with forward one side rotated. I kept trying to play with the values of the forward vector but none of my attempts produced a good result. If anyone has some good ideas i would love to hear them.

```
public class CarMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public Transform car;
    public float speed = 17;

    Vector3 forward = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
    Vector3 backward = new Vector3(0, 0, -1);

    Vector3 rotationRight = new Vector3(0, 30, 0);
    Vector3 rotationLeft = new Vector3(0, -30, 0);

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("w"))                                         
        {
            rb.MovePosition(car.position + forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("s"))
        {
            rb.MovePosition(car.position  + backward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            Quaternion deltaRotationRight = Quaternion.Euler(rotationRight * Time.deltaTime);
            rb.MoveRotation(rb.rotation * deltaRotationRight);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            Quaternion deltaRotationLeft = Quaternion.Euler(rotationLeft * Time.deltaTime);
            rb.MoveRotation(rb.rotation * deltaRotationLeft);
        }

    }
}
```

*Later edit: The reason I asked this question is that I didn't knew that the vector car.forward is different than the static vector I wrote. After the explanation in the comments I undestand what i have done wrong.*

Comment: In that question I don't understand how the code from the answer in different than the code from question. This is my first unity project and I don't really know all that well how things work. And i feel that I am already doing the code it is written there.

Comment: You should be using the transform's forward vector instead of 0, 0, 1. That's a static value. Use `car.forward`

Comment: @Eliasar you were right. Never thought that those vectors were actually different things. Now it moves like it supposed to. Looks like i learned a thing today.Should i delete this question since it looks it is a duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `rb.MovePosition()` you can use `transform.Translate()`. It moves an object using Transform instead of Rigidbody, also you can overload this method and choose whenever you want to move an object relative to space or itself, more [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html). Here is working version

```
public Rigidbody rb;
public Transform car;
public float speed = 17;


Vector3 rotationRight = new Vector3(0, 30, 0);
Vector3 rotationLeft = new Vector3(0, -30, 0);

Vector3 forward = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
Vector3 backward = new Vector3(0, 0, -1);

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetKey("w"))
    {
        transform.Translate(forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("s"))
    {
        transform.Translate(backward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey("d"))
    {
        Quaternion deltaRotationRight = Quaternion.Euler(rotationRight * Time.deltaTime);
        rb.MoveRotation(rb.rotation * deltaRotationRight);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey("a"))
    {
        Quaternion deltaRotationLeft = Quaternion.Euler(rotationLeft * Time.deltaTime);
        rb.MoveRotation(rb.rotation * deltaRotationLeft);
    }

}
```

Comment: Vector3.Forward is the same as Vector3(0, 0, 1)

Comment: It is, but you don't have to introduce another variable

Comment: I said that because it doesn't solve the problem. It's the same as the problem.

Comment: All right, I changed that to be same as in question if it's really a problem.

Comment: No, the issue is that Vector3.Foward is not the right value. car.forward needs to be used instead. This translates the car one unit in the z direction instead of where the car is facing

Comment: No, transform.Translate uses cars rotation value by default. I've tested it before answering the question.